# Word/phrase to describe something popular due to its availability

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

How can I describe something (tool, method, etc.) that is common in use but not necessarily for its quality, unique features and effectiveness.

In fact, it is kind of popular because it's easy to obtain and highly available.

Comment: so for a physical product, it has good "distribution" and that's the main reason it's popular?

Comment: So this thing is the "de facto standard"? It is very hard to see that something is popular for the reasons you cite, I would imagine it is easily available *because* it became popular rather than the other way around?

Comment: :-) general, extensive, universal, common, global, worldwide, international, omnipresent, ubiquitous, wholesale, all-embracing, all-inclusive, all-round, across the board, far-reaching, predominant, prevalent, rife, broad, blanket, sweeping, rampant, catholic, inescapable, pervading, pervasive, permeating, epidemic

Comment: maybe widespread?

Comment: @MarvMills, It seems OK. it's such a "standard", However I want to critique this belief in my essay. So, I think that I should not call it standard!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word [*ubiquitous*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+ubiquitous&oq=define+ubiquitous) describes something that is seen and used everywhere.

It doesn't have any connotations of quality that you seek.  It simply derives from the Latin *ubique*, meaning *everywhere*.

Comment: Something can be ubiquitous woithout being popular.

Comment: @Chenmunka, as in my response to _Marv_, I do not want to bold the popularity but only its widespreadness. So, **ubiquitous** seems to be what I'm looking for. (before acceptance :), +1)

Answer (score 0):

You could say it's the **default** or the **default option**.  "Something that is usual or standard" ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/default)).

Or informally, it's the **go-to** option.  "Any item or object which is the most commonly used or which you use without having to think about it" ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=go-to&defid=3439129)).